# oracle query is not using indexes

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I am brand new to Oracle and although I have used SQL Server fairly extensively I have not had the need to delve deeply into the details of database design ... specifically INDEXES. So I have spent a good deal of time sitting through tutorials on Indexes ... both in concept as well as Oracle specific.

In an effort to put my understanding into practice I set up a VERY simple table with some basic indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."TBL_PERSON" 
   (    
        "PERSON_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "FIRST_NAME" NVARCHAR2(120) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "MIDDLE_NAME" NVARCHAR2(120), 
        "LAST_NAME" NVARCHAR2(120) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "DOB" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "IS_MALE" NCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'T' NOT NULL ENABLE,
        CONSTRAINT "TBL_PERSON_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PERSON_ID")
   )
```

As you can see the PERSON_ID field contains the unique ROWID for each record in the table and is an auto-incrementing Primary Key.

(please don't get hung up on missing SQL unless it pertains to the issue of INDEXES not working. I tried to select only the relevant SQL from the DDL and may have missed some items. There was a ton of stuff there that I didn't think was relevant to this issue so I tried to trim it out)

I have created a couple of additional non-clustered indexes on the table.

```
CREATE INDEX "SYSTEM"."IDX_LAST_NAME" ON "SYSTEM"."TBL_PERSON" ("LAST_NAME") 
CREATE INDEX "SYSTEM"."IDX_PERSON_NAME" ON "SYSTEM"."TBL_PERSON" ("FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME")
```

When I run an "Explain Plan" on the following SQL I get notified that the PK index was used as expected.

```
select * from TBL_PERSON where PERSON_ID = 21
```

[image]

However when I run a query to select someone with a particular LAST_NAME the LAST_NAME index seems to go ignored.

```
select * from TBL_PERSON where LAST_NAME = 'Stenstrom'
```

[image]

Why would it not use IDX_LAST_NAME? For what it's worth I have the same issue with the composite index IDX_PERSON_NAME.

Comment: Not related directly to your current question but some things that will make the transition to Oracle easier... Never create your own objects in the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schemas, create a new schema for your objects. `SYS` and `SYSTEM` are reserved by Oracle and functionality does occasionally behave differently there. `ROWID` is a reserved word in Oracle and refers to the physical address of a row not the primary key value. It is rare that you would want to use `NVARCHAR2` data types in new development, choose a Unicode character set and use `VARCHAR2` instead.

Comment: Additionally, Oracle has no such thing as a clustered index so referring to indexes as "non-clustered" can only be confusing.  The closest thing in Oracle to a clustered index is an index-organized table-- if you talk about a "non-clustered index", folks may assume that you have an index organized table rather than the heap-organized table that you actually created.

Comment: How many rows does the table `tbl_person` contain? And how many are returned by the query on `LAST_NAME`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name (America! nice:) ) -I have upped the count to about 25+ records. On this particular query there would be 8 records returned.

Comment: @Justin Cave - Thanks for the advice. Doesn't the NVARCHAR2 however, cover international character sets?

Comment: For 8 out of 25 rows using an index does not make sense. The 25 rows will probably all reside on the same database block, which means that the full table scan is just a single I/O operation - 2 at the most. An index scan for larger tables is usually only effective if the query returns not more than approx. 10-15% of the total number of rows.

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom - `NVARCHAR2` columns use the national character set. Normally, yes, that is Unicode.  However, if you plan on storing Unicode data, you're much better off choosing a Unicode-based database character set and relying on `VARCHAR2` types.  You'd only use `NVARCHAR2` if you're developing on a legacy system that doesn't support Unicode and whose database character set cannot be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to your question is the column "cardinality".  You have only five rows estimated as being returned for the table.

Oracle has a choice between two execution plans:

1. Load the data page.  Scan the five records on the data page and choose the one(s) that match the condition.
2. Load the index and scan it for the match.  Then load the data page and lookup the matching record(s).

Oracle has concluded that for five records, the first approach is faster.  If you load more data into the table, you should see the execution plan change.  Alternatively, if you had `select last_name` instead of `select *`, then Oracle might very well choose the index.

Comment: +1 But it's worth noting that cardinality 5 is not Oracle's estimate of the total number of rows in the table, it's the estimate of the number of rows returned after filtering.

Comment: Approximately how many records would it take to engage the index? Hundreds, thousands, etc.? I have 25 in there now and still not using the index ... and I'm running out of family members!! LOL

Comment: I added 2020 more rows and indexes started showing up in the "Explain Plan" - Thanks!!